# How to show that $\pi =3+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{(2n+1)!!}{(2n+3)(2n+4)(n+1)!2^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How to show that $$\pi =3+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{(2n+1)!!}{(2n+3)(2n+4)(n+1)!2^n}$$
I don't have an idea how to start.Any help to prove it?

Comment: @rogerl,please check the formula again there is a $(n+1)!$ in the  denominator

Comment: I will give you one idea. Try generating function of [Catalan numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number). I think it will lead to the solution.

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay: In fact, it is about playing with a variation on the MacLaurin series of $\arcsin$.

Comment: @AlexM., nice, looking at the form Catalan numbers came instantly to me, but I did not think about $\sin^{-1}x$. Ok, lets write the solutions then.

Comment: Mathematica sums $\sum a_n x^n$ as the extremely unweildy $\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{1-x}+1} \left(-x+2 \sqrt{1-x}-2\right)+4 \sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-x}} \left(\sqrt{1-x}+1\right) \sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-x}}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}{\sqrt{\sqrt{1-x}+1} x^2}$. Evaluated at $x=1$ it indeed gives $\pi - 3$. Note that the integral of this expression is the slightly more managable $\frac{2}{\sqrt{1-x}+1}-2 \log \left(\sqrt{1-x}+1\right)-\frac{8 \sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-x}}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}{\sqrt{x}}$.

Comment: Now that you have not just one, but two solutions to your problem, could you please tell us how you (or somebody else) came up with this problem? In what context?

Comment: Oftentimes I wished downvoting cost more points so that people abusing it should lose more and think twice before doing it. I have upvoted this question in order to cancel a gratuitous negative vote.

Comment: @krvolok: Note that if $x>0$ then $2 \arcsin \frac {\sqrt {1- \sqrt{1-x}}} {\sqrt 2} = \arcsin \sqrt{1-x} + \log 2$. Sometimes Mathematica misses the lightest form of an expression and further simplifications are necessary.

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay: Funny (and frustrating) to see that we all spend time and effort here trying to solve the problem, and the OP seems to have gone missing in action.

Comment: @AlexM. yes, it was unfortunate for the OP to miss the journey. Maybe it was just a misalignment of timings.

Answer (score 4):

You can express the series as $$S=\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{1}{2n+1}C_{n}x^{2n}$$ where $C_n$ is the $n$ th Catalan number and $x=\frac{1}{2}$. You can find the definition and generating function expressions for Catalan numbers [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number). Then, if we write $f(t)=\sum_{n\ge 0}C_n t^n$, we see that $$xS=\int_{0}^{x}(f(t^2)-C_0)dt\\=\int_{0}^{x}\left(\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{1-4t^2}}-1\right)dt\\=\int_{0}^{x}\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4t^2}}{1+\sqrt{1-4t^2}}dt\\=\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{1-\cos 2\theta}{1+\cos2\theta}\cos 2\theta d\theta\quad(\mbox{Using $2t=\sin 2\theta$ and $x=1/2$} ) \\=\int_{0}^{\pi/4}(2\sin^2\theta-\tan^2\theta)d\theta\\=\pi/2-3/2\\\implies S=\pi-3$$ since $x=1/2$.

Answer (score 2):

Since it is unpleasant to type in LaTeX too much, I'll just sketch the answer, leaving some details for you to fill in.

First, insert the missing even terms (i.e. $(2n+2)!!$) both in the numerator and in the denominator, then use that $(2n+2)!! = (n+1)! 2^{n+1}$ and $(2n+2)!! (2n+1)!! = (2n+2)!$ in order to get the nicer series $\sum \limits _{n \geq 0} \frac {(2n+2)!} {(2n+3) (2n+4) (n+1)!^2 2^{2n+1}}$.

Now, produce a power series by inserting $x^{2n+4}$ into the previous series, obtaining $$f(x)=\sum \limits _{n \geq 0} \frac {(2n+2)!} {(2n+3) (2n+4) (n+1)!^2 2^{2n+1}} x^{2n+4}$$. We'd like to show that $f(1)= \pi -3$.

Note that $$f'(x)=\sum \limits _{n \geq 0} \frac {(2n+2)!} {(2n+3) (n+1)!^2 2^{2n+1}} x^{2n+3} = \sum \limits _{n \geq -1} \frac {(2n+2)!} {(2n+3) (n+1)!^2 2^{2n+1}} x^{2n+3} - 2x = 2 \sum \limits _{m \geq 0} \frac {(2m)!} {(2m+1) m!^2 2^{2m}} x^{2m+1} - 2x$$, and this last series is precisely the Taylor series of $\arcsin$ around $0$, so $$f'(x) = 2 \arcsin x -2x$$, whence (after an integration by parts), you get $$f(x) = 2x \arcsin x +2 \sqrt{1-x^2}-x^2+C$$, where $C$ is an integration constant that you fix by noting that $f(0)=0$ which gives you $C=-2$.

Finally, you compute $f(1)=\pi -3$.

Comment: Nice observations, Alex.